# Removing a row in a matrix using a variable

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have a (2x10) matrix.

Now I have a function to iteratively scroll through these rows, perform a cleaning process, and if some criteria is met, delete that row.  So the function is returning (usually) a row of the original size, and sometimes removing that row.  So, in other words, removal of a row is being done through a variable being returned by the function.

However, it throws an error regarding dimension mismatch.

So, I can do this:

```
x(1,:) = [];
```

To delete the first row,
but:

```
d = [];
x(1,:) = d;
```

Gives a dimension mismatch error. 
So if I give:

```
x(1,:) = cleaning_function(x(1,:));
```

and the function decides to remove the row, it will throw up a dimension mismatch error.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: It would be better if your cleaning function would take the full matrix as input, and return an index of all the row to remove ... then the next line of code you can check if the result is empty, if not then use it to actually remove the rows to delete in one go.

Answer (score 0):

The `= []` is an idiom, and does not conform to the usual assignment rules (it is interpreted as "delete the LHS", more or less). That's why your idea isn't working. As Hoki says, the result you're aiming at would not be the most efficient. Still, you may have other concerns not revealed in your question. If so, the closest I can think of is to use a form as:

```
if cleaning_function(x(1, :))
    x(1, :) = [];
end
```

But Hoki's idea, or something similar, will be cleaner. For instance:

```
rows_to_keep = cleaning_function(x);
x = x(rows_to_keep, :);
```

Or, even:

```
x = cleaning_function(x)
```

with the details handled internally in a loop. Since Matlab passes by reference, the above is generally not an overhead.

Comment: No, Matlab passes by value in general. The example you gave is an optimization done for matrices and requires the input/output variables to share the same name.

Comment: I meant that there would not be an additional copy needed on the call, or on the return, as was once the case in Matlab. Of course, the semantics are always pass by value for simple objects. I was not aware that the pass-by-reference optimisation was lost if the names were different, though. Do you have a reference for that? It seems very weird.

Comment: I got it from this [Matlabcentral discussion](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/49390-pass-variable-by-reference-to-function#comment_259555)

Comment: Hi Setsu. I don't see any indication of that on that discussion page. Moreover, I just tested this in Matlab: the name doesn't seem to matter, it's the code flow that makes the difference. My understanding is that Matlab has a fairly comprehensive copy-on-write policy in current releases, but I haven't seen an updated report on it since 2006!

Comment: I've just confirmed this behavior on R2014a on Windows. Create a function that modifies element (1,1) of the matrix and pass it back. Create data `a = ones(10000,50000)`; observe the memory use in task manager. Calling the function like `a = myFunc(a);` causes a spike in memory but returns shortly; calling the function like `b = myFunc(a)` causes the memory usage to double, confirming that the data has been copied.

Comment: Hi Setsu. I've just tried this both in a script and at the command prompt (Linux R2014b). And the naming of variables makes no difference to performance that I can identify. I don't know the general answer, perhaps the version is important - R2014b was a fairly major overhaul, I understand, and I know Mathworks have been playing catch up on this under-the-hood stuff for years.

Comment: Thanks guys, I modified the function to utilize the whole matrix, and it's now working perfectly.

Comment: Wow. So, I just flipped over to Windows, and I absolutely agree, Setsu. Code that is logically identical, but breaks the A=F(A) rule (i.e. by doing B=F(A); A=B;) takes much longer to complete. What a fail. And why does it work fine on Linux...?